elf_open: Invalid argument while building debian packages
I am trying to build a debian package via jenkins, but there is an error I receive while running the command: "dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot".
the error that I receive every time is:
open: No such file or directory
elf_open: Invalid argument
make[1]: *** [debian/rules:23: override_dh_install] Error 1

debian/rules code is:
#! /usr/bin/make -f

export DH_VERBOSE = 1
export DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS = noautodbgsym

%:
    dh $@ 

override_dh_testdir:
override_dh_update_autotools_config:
override_dh_autoreconf:
override_dh_auto_configure:
override_dh_auto_build:
override_dh_auto_test:
override_dh_installchangelogs:
override_dh_shlibdeps:
    dh_shlibdeps -- -lbuild/thirdparty/lib
override_dh_builddeb:
    dh_builddeb --destdir=.
override_dh_auto_install:
override_dh_auto_clean:
override_dh_install:
    chrpath -r /opt/package_name/proxy/lib build/bin/package_name-proxy
    chrpath -r /opt/package_name/proxy/lib build/lib/libtvs-cmnutils.so
    chrpath -r /opt/package_name/proxy/lib build/lib/libtvs-proxycommon.so
    chrpath -r /opt/package_name/proxy/lib build/lib/libtvs-proxydb.so
    chrpath -r /opt/package_name/proxy/lib build/lib/libtvs-proxymain.so
    chrpath -r /opt/package_name/proxy/lib build/lib/libtvs-proxypelco.so
    chrpath -r /opt/package_name/proxy/lib build/lib/libtvs-live555.so
    chrpath -r /opt/package_name/proxy/lib build/lib/libtvs-proxylive555.so
    chrpath -r /opt/package_name/proxy/lib build/thirdparty/lib/libsvsCrypto.so
    chrpath -r /opt/package_name/proxy/lib build/thirdparty/lib/libUsageEnvironment.so.3.1.0
    chrpath -r /opt/package_name/proxy/lib build/thirdparty/lib/libliveMedia.so.106.1.1
    chrpath -r /opt/package_name/proxy/lib build/thirdparty/lib/libgroupsock.so.30.0.10
    chrpath -r /opt/package_name/proxy/lib build/thirdparty/lib/libBasicUsageEnvironment.so.1.0.1
    dh_install

If you need more information for debugging the issue, just let me know and I will update the post.
